# how to get pdfcrop2 script

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm often interested in cropping pdfs,* and one tool I use to do this is Heiko Oberdiek's script [`pdfcrop.pl`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfcrop/). I would like to try [`pdfcrop2`](http://code.google.com/p/pdfcrop2/), a fork of `pdfcrop.pl`, but the [Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/pdfcrop2/) (the only source of information I've found about `pdfcrop2`) only has patches to an old version of `pdfcrop.pl`, which I can't find a copy of. Does anybody know where I can either get a copy of `pdfcrop2` or version 1.5 of `pdfcrop.pl`?

*In addition to getting ahold of a working copy of pdfcrop2, I'd be happy to learn about any other tools (preferably Free) that can be used to crop pdfs. [`pdftk`](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) is fantastic for doing just about anything other than cropping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: The full pdfcrop2 is available in their svn repo: http://code.google.com/p/pdfcrop2/source/browse/trunk/pdfcrop.pl

Original answer.

pdfcrop 1.5 was shipped with debian and ubuntu; looking in the orig.tar.gz for the [texlive-bin source package](http://packages.debian.org/source/texlive-base) which you can grab from [a nearby Debian mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list) should work.

Comment: Thanks Stobor! I can't believe I didn't notice the svn repo on the google code page. I couldn't check out the repo you posted, but this one worked: `svn checkout pdfcrop2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk pdfcrop2-read-only`. As for pdfcrop 1.5, it turns out that it's also included in the package `texlive-extra-utils` which was easier for me to grab (I'm running ubuntu and I couldn't find a `texlive-bin` package among my current sources).

Answer (score 2):

I have played a bit with pyPdf for setting page boxes.  Below is some test code to generate a PDF with just the even pages, setting the media box and crop box top right to the same as the first page which could be a starting point for something more useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from pdfsave import pdfSave
import sys

def pdfSetBoxes(input, output, mediaBox, cropBox):
    numPages = input.getNumPages()
    for pageNum in range(1,numPages, 2):
        page = input.getPage(pageNum)
        page.mediaBox.upperRight = mediaBox
        page.cropBox.upperRight = cropBox
        output.addPage(page)

input = PdfFileReader(file(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()

page0 = input.getPage(0)
mb = page0.mediaBox.getUpperRight()
cb = page0.cropBox.getUpperRight()

pdfSetBoxes(input, output, mb, cb)
pdfSave(output, sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: The beginnings of another pyPdf based cropping script can be found here: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=25565

Comment: @AntonGeraschenko that script has apparently been [placed on GitHub](https://github.com/pboehm/pdfcrop) as well